# data-binding doesn't work after using "appendChild()" to add new element

Tags: angularjs

when i write like this, angular works:

```
<html ng-app="mptmanager" class="ng-scope">
     <body>
         <input ng-model = "test" /><br />
         {{test}}
     </body>
 </html>
 <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="angular/angularModules.js"></script>
```

but when i run JS code like this:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = '<input ng-model = "test2"><br />{{test2}}';
document.body.appendChild(temp);
```

angular has no effect to the new element, so i can only see "{{test2}}" on my page...

how can i make angular work when i try to add or change some element on my page with JS?

Comment: You should look into angular directives, which is the place to make dom modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never do DOM manipulation outside of directives when using Angular. Just to be complete, I'll show you how to make that work anyway. Just inject the `$compile` service and compile the new markup with the scope.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.foo = 'Default value';

  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.innerHTML = '<input ng-model="foo">{{foo}}';
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  $compile(elem)($scope);
});
```

**Here are proper approaches using directives:**

```
<div my-directive></div>
<div my-directive2></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<input ng-model="foo">{{foo}}'
  };
});

app.directive('myDirective2', function() {
  return {
    compile: function(element) {
      element.html('<input ng-model="foo">{{foo}}');
    }
  };
});
```

In your directive, if you use the `link` function, which has access to `scope`, you will have to manually `$compile` the markup as I demonstrated above, but be careful to avoid an infinite loop. You will usually do this: `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` If you $compile the element itself, you would create an infinite loop.

**[Live demos (click).](http://jsbin.com/piwox/2/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

As dskh briefly mentioned, [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) are used to do that kind of stuff in Angular.

The issue here is that Angular *doesn't know* about the new element, as the routine which adds it lives outside of the Angular scope. You could call `$scope.$apply()` manually, but i won't consider this best practice.