# Angular directive and attributes Don't work when created and set inside Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive :

```
app.directive('toggleText', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element,attr) {

            element.bind('click', function(evt) {
                alert('hello');
            });
        }
    };
})
```

it works when i add it to an element. it alerts "hello".

However when i try to create an element inside my controller and add the directive in this fashion:

```
var myElement = document.createElement('div');
var attr = document.createAttribute('toggle-text');
myElement.setAttributeNode(attr);
```

I can see the directive is added to the element in my debugger but it doesn't work.
Same problem when trying to add ng-click, ng-include, .. and other angular attributes or directives inside my controller using "setAttributeNode".

Comment: You should never do DOM manipulation in a controller. That's what directives are for. The reason it doesn't work is because your changes aren't compiled with angular.

Comment: possible duplicate of [data-binding doesn't work after using "appendChild()" to add new element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645146/data-binding-doesnt-work-after-using-appendchild-to-add-new-element)

Comment: @m59 thank you . I gave u an up vote on that page, this was exactly what was looking for.  but i still have to create <div my-directive></div>  inside my controller, as you explained there i use $compile . thanks

Comment: Why do you have to do it in the controller? I promise you, there is no circumstance ever where DOM manipulation needs to be done in the controller.

Comment: when users click on a button, it must create a <div> with attributes and directives. I guess i can have a directive on the button to do that as well. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: It sounds like you just want `<div ng-if="buttonIsClicked"></div>` and `<button ng-click="buttonIsClicked = true">Click me!</button>`

Comment: i still need to create <div ng-if="buttonIsClicked"></div>  some how.  if user clicks 10 times, there must be 10 of these divs.  I think as u mentioned i have to figure it out inside a directive.

Comment: =D http://jsbin.com/biwabo/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Do not manually do DOM manipulation and etc. inside a controller; angular is not designed to deal with that. Instead, use `$compile`.

Something like this: (controller code)

```
function($scope, $compile) {
    var myElement = $compile('<div toggle-text></div>')($scope);
    // do stuff with it
}
```